# How to diagnose failure to create process when running windows executable from a network share

Tags: python, windows, filesystems, pytest

I would like to run some Windows binaries from a network share to remove update and installation issues across our large collection of test and developer machines.  The specific package in question is Pytest.  I have a copy of python (2.7.6) installed on the network share and it works fine.  Using this python, I installed pytest onto the network share using my account.  My account is special because it's the only one with read/write access to the network share--all other accounts have read-only access.

After installing pytest, I ran the executable py.test.exe in the Scripts directory and it was able to run

```
    X:\python\2.7.6\windows\x86>Scripts\py.test.exe
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.6 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! KeyboardInterrupt !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
X:\python\2.7.6\windows\x86\lib\ntpath.py:401: KeyboardInterrupt
==============================  in 18.30 seconds ==============================

X:\python\2.7.6\windows\x86>
```

However, other users cannot run this executable, and get the message

```
failed to create process
```

If pytest is installed on a local drive there is no problem.  I have performed the following experiments:

- Run py.test locally as an administrator: works
- Run py.test locally as a regular user: fails to create process
- Run from network share using my special id: works
- Run from network share using 'regular' id (which has Administrator rights on that PC): fails to create process
- Run from network share using 'regular' id and specifically run in a window as Administrator: fails to create process

I had a couple of theories that the py.test.exe must be

1. Run as administrator and possibly
2. Run from a directory with read/write permissions

I tried sorting all files in the network folder by time stamp to see if perhaps there was some file (like a .pid) being created that was stymied by the read-only nature of the network share, but I didn't see anything, so the read/write aspect may not be applicable.  So, it appears that somehow binaries running from a network share are not run with administrator privileges, except for my special id.

Anyone know why and how I can address this?  [Using EnableLinkedConnections GPO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee844140%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) seemed to be related but the symptom is different and in fact did not help.

Any suggestions on how to further diagnose the problem?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that Python, for whatever reason, is attempting to gain write access to the executable or a related file.  Process Monitor is probably your best bet to diagnose exactly what is happening, although you could also search the Python source code for the "failed to create process" string and try to identify the problem that way.

Comment: Hmm, I was assuming that since py.test.exe was an executable, it was the one that would call python and not the other way around i.e. that it's a fundamental windows problem rather than something related to python.

Comment: If "failed to create process" is the exact error message, I'm fairly sure it isn't coming from Windows.  In any case Windows has no problem running an executable from a read-only network share, we use that functionality regularly at my workplace.  I expect that `py.test.exe` is either attempting and failing to launch a Python instance, or it is successfully launching a Python instance which is either failing to initialize properly or failing to load and run the  Python code.  But if in doubt, Process Monitor will show you whether `py.test.exe` gets started or not.

Comment: PS: there is an issue where you cannot run applications from network shares if they require privilege elevation (because elevated processes run in a different context from the point of view of the component that handles network shares) but the symptoms are different to those you describe, and it seems unlikely that you require privilege elevation anyway.